# BMC Control-M - can it manage remote offsite servers

Tags: control-m

Our organisation uses Control-M to manage all the scripts within our network.  However, we have recently entered a contract to have a new application hosted for us.  It is an ecommerce application and has scripts run through Cron jobs.

What I'd like to know is that whether Control-M has any offsite agent functionality so that it can be installed on this remote site and then in some way keep in communication with the Control-M server we have within our infrastructure so that we can monitor the scripts along with the rest of our applications.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so off-topic here. It might be ok on Server Fault, but you'll need to describe your scenario in more detail., especially why the normal agent setup (or agentless thing) doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-M supports Agents anywhere as long as you have network connectivity. The default Server/Agent ports are 7005-7012 inclusive, so those will need opening on any firewall.

If you don't want the remote site to use the full Agent (which will need a local install) then you can use the Agentless option (works via WMI on Windows or SSH for Unix) and only needs defining on the Control-M Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about you question. Control-M server works with tcp/ip to contact its agents and does not care if it is connecting to a server in the same datacenter or on another continent.

Install a VPN between you and your hosted application and install a control-m agent or setup an agentless scheduling using ssh and you are good to go.